# How to sum Column, using Less Than Equal to from a Slicer Value

Tags: powerbi, dax

Unable to sum the columns with the filters

I have a slicer that indicates the Month Number. I have a table that I would like to sum based on the month that are Equal or Less Than the selected Month. Something similar to a YTD.

```
YTDBudget = if(SwitchCurrency[SelectedValue] = "USD",
CALCULATE(
SUM(BdgFcst[USD.Budget]),
FILTER(BdgFcst,BdgFcst[MonthNumber]<SELECTEDVALUE(YTDCalculation[MonthNumber]))
,FILTER(BdgFcst,BdgFcst[Country]="SG")
),
CALCULATE(
SUM(BdgFcst[LC.Budget]),
FILTER(BdgFcst,BdgFcst[MonthNumber]<SELECTEDVALUE(YTDCalculation[MonthNumber]))
,FILTER(BdgFcst,BdgFcst[Country]="SG")
))
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L6iI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your `CALCULATE`/`FILTER` set-up seems incorrect. You should be using:

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM( BdgFcst[USD.Budget] ),
    FILTER(
        BdgFcst,
        BdgFcst[MonthNumber] < SELECTEDVALUE( YTDCalculation[MonthNumber] )
            && BdgFcst[Country] = "SG"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i faced another issue with the place holder. Seems like i couldnt put together the Switching of Currency along with the SelectedValue.

I managed to split them all up into 3 different measures respectively and it works though
1. The chosing of Measures with the selection of Currency below
2. Calculating USD Budget as 1 Measure
3. Calculating LC Budget as another